# Test Multiple Criteria in VBA DO While loop

Tags: vba, loops, criteria

I am trying to edit some VBA code which currently loops until a certain test is met. What I would like to do is loop until two conditions are met. I am having trouble getting it do so. Here is the original code, which works.

```
    Loop
    For j = 1 To 29
    Increment = Worksheets("Price & Energy Curve").Cells(8 + Start + j, 3).Value
    l = Int((Worksheets("Capacity").Cells(57 + j, 12).Value) * (-1) / Increment)
    k = WorksheetFunction.Max((l + 1) * Increment, 0)
    Worksheets("Capacity").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Cells(56 + j, 17).Value = k
    test = ActiveSheet.Cells(57 + j, 13).Value
    Do While test <> True
    k = k + Increment
    ActiveSheet.Cells(56 + j, 17).Value = k
    test = ActiveSheet.Cells(57 + j, 13).Value
    Loop
    Next j
```

I would like to add the additional test of

```
   test = ActiveSheet.Cells(57 + j, 37).Value
```

So that when

```
   test = ActiveSheet.Cells(57 + j, 13).Value
```

and

```
  test = ActiveSheet.Cells(57 + j, 37).Value
```

are true, the loop exits.

Comment: you have written the answer in your question `if test = ActiveSheet.Cells(57 + j, 13).Value and test = ActiveSheet.Cells(57 + j, 37).Value then exit do

Answer (score 0):

Check this loop

```
Do While test1 <> True Or test2 <> True
k = k + Increment
ActiveSheet.Cells(56 + j, 17).Value = k
test1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(57 + j, 13).Value
test2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(57 + j, 37).Value
Loop
```